# Managing the default order of a table in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scope, elasticsearch

I have a model which has over 40,000 entires in it. I want to be able to have this table permanently sorted by one of its attributes.  The tricky part of this is that some of the elements have a nil value for the attribute I want to sort by.

Some poking around has led me to `default_scope`, but it appears this is being deprecated and everyone warns against it.  It seems like putting `default_scope order('director_id DESC')` or something like this would fix things, but this doesn't take into account nil values.  What is the better alternative?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
I'm also using Tire with ElasticSearch for managing searches.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's best to be explicit with model scopes. You can just do:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.default_order
    order('director_id DESC NULLS LAST')
  end
end
```

Your database will have a syntax as part of `ORDER BY` for the placement of NULL values. If you don't want NULL values in the output at all then you can add a `where` call and the method should be renamed.

Comment: Ah, sorry, apparently MySQL doesn't have sensible behaviour for NULL values in an ORDER BY clause. If you're using MySQL you'd probably need to `COALESCE` the column in the `SELECT` to an arbitrary number.

Comment: I'm using Postgres in prod, SQLite in dev

Comment: Postgres supports the syntax in the answer. :)

Comment: So I just add these 3 lines to my model, and when I run a query from a controller it will automatically be sorted and no other work needs to be done?

Comment: No, you have to call `MyModel.default_order.all`. `default_scope` causes way more harm over time due to unexpected behaviour and changing requirements than typing a few extra characters. :)
Note that `def self.by_director` may be a better method name.

Comment: It's a bad idea to use a different database between development and production. Postgres is lightweight enough and easy to install on any platform used for development.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Since my table has >40k entires into it, I'd rather not call this method every time I run a search. Would it be best to just put this in a rake task and have it run only when I make an edit to the table?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44195/discussion-between-xml-slayer-and-andrew-france)